# Modify semi-major axis in WPF ellipse

Tags: wpf, ellipse

I want to modify the semi-major axis off a WPF ellipse, because I need to create an ellipse that looks like an egg. Also I need to fill the ellipse with an ImageBrush, so a Grid with DrawingBrush is not really an option. Any ideas how I can make this?

**Update**

Like Clemens suggested, [here](http://a0.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_3.png) is a link to a picture how I like to have it :)

Answer (score 1):

An Ellipse has a `Width` and a `Height`. The larger one of both defines the major axis, and half of it is called the [semi-major axis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-major_axis).

The Ellipse may be filled with an ImageBrush by its `Fill` property.

```
<Ellipse Width="400" Height="300">
    <Ellipse.Fill>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Jellyfish.jpg"/>
    </Ellipse.Fill>
</Ellipse>
```

An alternative would be to use a Path with an `EllipseGeometry`, which has `RadiusX` and `RadiusY` properties. The larger one of these directly defines the semi-major axis.

```
<Path>
    <Path.Data>
        <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="200" RadiusY="150"/>
    </Path.Data>
    <Path.Fill>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Jellyfish.jpg"/>
    </Path.Fill>
</Path>
```

In order to create an asymmetric, egg-like shape you may combine two [elliptical arc segments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745030.aspx) like this:

```
<Path Data="M 0,-150 A 150,150 0 1 0 0,150 A 200,150 0 0 0 0,-150">
    <Path.Fill>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Jellyfish.jpg"/>
    </Path.Fill>
</Path>
```

Comment: Helped, but it seems not to work like I need it... So I think I will simply use a normal ellipse :)

Comment: Well, in order to get it working like "you need it", you would have to get a little more precise about what exacly you're going to achieve. Perhaps draw a sketch.

Comment: Then what's wrong with a combination of two elliptical arc segments?

Comment: This idea is great, but how can I put the picture in this "egg"?

Comment: Which picture? The "egg" is all white. And after all, my answer shows you exactly how to fill a shape with an ImageBrush. If you can't transfer that to your concrete problem, it would perhaps be best to start over with a WPF book.

Comment: Well, I said it wrong. The problem ist, that the "egg" is not really resizable. So the Arc Segments are no real solution.